# Summing all rows dependent on two column values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am attempting to sum all rows from a dataframe which have a specific column value. For example, I have

| Year | Division | **Species.Name** | **Metric.Tonnes** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1960 | 1A | Cod | 300 |
| 1960 | 1B | Cod | 200 |
| 1960 | 1A | Prawn | 50 |
| 1960 | 1B | Prawn | 100 |
| 1961 | 1A | Cod | 300 |
| 1961 | 1B | Cod | 200 |
| 1961 | 1A | Prawn | 50 |
| 1961 | 1B | Prawn | 100 |

and am trying to create a table which shows

| Year | **Species.Name** | **Metric.Tonnes** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1960 | Cod | 500 |
| 1960 | Prawn | 150 |
| 1961 | Cod | 500 |
| 1961 | Prawn | 150 |

which has summed all species from a particular year, regardless of division.

I attempted to use the group function to no avail.

```
df %>% group_by(Year,Species.Name) %>% dplyr::summarise(across(Metric.Tonnes),sum)
```

Comment: You should put the function within the across function: `summarise(across(Metric.Tonnes, sum))`. Note that `summarise(Metric.Tonnes = sum(Metric.Tonnes))` works well here as well, no need for `across`

Comment: Greatly appreciate you spotting this mistake. If you would like to add your comment as a reply I can mark this as the correct solution :)